# when use enum as key of a object literal, if i assign enum key object, i can use regardless of the type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

If I use enum as Index Signatures for an object and have a random value of enum as a key, it will be saved regardless of the type. How can we solve this?

I am attaching the link that I tested.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgZTsKIBOMDeAUDCTALKIQCWwMAvDAIwA0xpAYlQDaoMBMrUjADCOOAEMoVAG5UoAT3owAzIQC+hQnAAeAB1ywqYKHBwAzccDgiu4iBAJsS4nFOgA5ccjgAuGNBwjAHMAbicYKSguX38oQLBQ8KgACxQAIzBxbj8A4LCNLT0DCPldawwsXGFLZOsGIiEAbQhMbBwASQATGCN0VtwAXQB+P2Fbe0aB-LDCUEhYBTKAFThoJQAKFyC-Crbq4FqASnoAPkchLfzNaNgWyo7Olegd-rwGXdwAOgpqYE07tpdJ6wBhkSTJT44cRgTogZDrY5nAAMnwArDAhn17p9RBIpLIFDA-GCUpDobD4YiYCj0ZiPjhvpQaESsW1PpweJoAPRcjFDWbgNYmNYve77WpKfDNV5A1ZQAYsgDkdk6io0wqgMx5fMIizgwPWDVI0vusugAz8jD4ylYakOQA

Comment: Please put your example code as plain text also.

Comment: See the answer to the linked question for more information.